# encrypt and decrypt xml file content

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have large xml file with more than 30 000 lines. It has content like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <Nodes>
      <Node>some node name </Node>
      <Node>some node name 2 </Node>
      ...
   </Nodes>
```

I want to send this xml file with encrypted content to the client manually. Client app (wpf) will load this file and encrypt this file on demand without user intervention (all possible keys will be predefined earlier on this client app).

What method should I use to encrypt and decrypt xml file content?

I was thinking to use
http://aspnettutorialonline.blogspot.com/2012/05/encryption-and-decryption-in-aspnet.html

but since I do not have much experience with this subject I'm asking is this good solution or you would recommend something else?

Comment: What are you trying to defend against? If the keys are hard-coded in the app, you have a very limited set of useful scenarios.

Comment: @SLaks this file will be send manually over time to the client, which will be loaded by user into app, so I dont want user to see xml content.

Comment: Then use the encryption and decryption methods used on the page that you have posted. Read in the XML file on the **client** side and call `EncryptIt(yourXmlString)` and on the **server** side call `DecryptIt(encryptedXmlString)`

Comment: Removed WPF tag as there is nothing WPF scpecific in the question. .NET encryption works the same regardless of the UI layer used...

Comment: If the user's app can read the file, the user can also read the file.  Period.

Answer (score 1):

AES encryption is very easy with .NET...

```
private readonly ICryptoTransform encryptor;
private readonly ICryptoTransform decryptor;
private readonly UTF8Encoding encoder;

var rm = new RijndaelManaged();
encryptor = rm.CreateEncryptor(key, vector);
decryptor = rm.CreateDecryptor(key, vector);
encoder = new UTF8Encoding();

public string Encrypt(string unencrypted)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(encoder.GetBytes(unencrypted)));         
}

public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] buffer)
{
    var encryptStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(encryptStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
    return encryptStream.ToArray();
}
```

`key` and `vector` are byte[] arrays as expected by the [RijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9df14hc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [RijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.createdecryptor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods...

The `key` and `vector` values will end up being a part of your client app code so hiding the values and obfuscating will protect only against non-sofisticated attackers but if all you need is to hide the xml contents from the non-technical end-users that might be sufficient...

Answer (score 0):

.Net provides many crypto-systems. Depending on your needs you can chose between DES, 3DES, AES or RSA(which is in efficient in your case). DES is the least secure, 3DES is better but I'd go for the AES. to Encrypt:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
...
class AES {
   private AesCryptoServiceProvider aes;
   public AES (Byte[] IV, Byte[] Key) {
       aes = AesCryptoServiceProvider();
       aes.Key = Key; // 256 Bits Long
       // AES Key can be generated using SHA256
       aes.IV = IV; // 128 Bits Long
       // IV can be generated using MD5
   }
   public Byte[] Encrypt(Byte[] FileStream) {
       ICryptoTransform Transform = aes.CreateEncryptor();
       return Transform.TransformFinalBlock(FileStream, 0, FileStream.Lenght);
   }     
   public Byte[] Decrypt (Byte[] FileStream){
       ICryptoTransform Transform = aes.CreateDecryptor();
       return Transform.TransformFinalBlock(FileStream, 0, FileStream.Lenght);
  }

}
```